# internet works only on recovery mode after network recover

Tags: network-manager

Every thing was working well, but suddenly internet stopped working on my laptop. When i log in using recovery mode the internet works but on normal boot internet does not work...

Comment: probably you are missing proprietary wifi drivers.

Comment: even lan is not working. Lan is working only on recovery mode as i enable networking in recovery mode

Comment: that's interesting, i don't know what would cause this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot your computer normally.
2. Search for or open Software Sources.
3. Make sure the `multiverse` and `universe` boxes are checked.
4. Switch to the rightmost tab, `Proprietary drivers` or so.
5. tick/select everything mentioned.
6. close Software Sources; if you are asked whether you would like to update database information now, click Yes/okay
7. open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get upgrade`, then enter your password when it asks.
8. reboot normally.

Comment: how do i search for open software sources

Comment: @user1140176 If you use Unity, open the dash and search for software sources.

Comment: i cannot find it in ubuntu 14.10. Only have software & updates